# Matautocomplete - Add a new object if the typed value is not in the list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I've an input box where a user can type any text. As the user is typing, an autocomplete panel shows up with highlighted option.

I want to do the following:

1. If the user types something, which does not match anything completely, an option in the autocomplete should show: "create new..."
2. Upon selecting "create new..." I should be able to retain the input value typed by the user, instead of changing it to "create new...".

For point 1, in the filters I put a "create new..." manually if the criteria is met, with the value of -1.

I'm not sure how to handle point 2. Code snippet:

**TS:**

```
  onCategorySelectionChanged(event, category?: Category) {
    console.log('first...on category selected');
    console.log(event.source.value);
    console.log(event.source.viewValue);

    if (category.id === -1) {
      console.log('retain the input value here...');
    }
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="autoCategory" 
formControlName="documentCategory"
matInput
type="text"
(blur)="categoryNameOnBlur()"
>
<mat-autocomplete #autoCategory="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayCategoryFn"
autoActiveFirstOption
>
<mat-option *ngFor="let category of filteredCategories | async" [value]="category"
                          (onSelectionChange)="onCategorySelectionChanged($event, category)">{{category.name}}
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Or if there is a better approach of adding a new value from list of values...I could look into that as well..

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: Yes its possible but provide a stackblitz to check

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apjlwf
the css is still missing but i guess, it should do..